# how make scrollbar works in mxgraph

Tags: mxgraph

When I drag A towards right and down ,I can view the whole graph by right and bottom scroll bar as follows:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g9hHu.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vtEbc.png)

But when I drag B towards left and upper , I can't view the whole graph even the scroll bar disappear as follows :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3M1IC.png)
I have set the 'overflow:auto' style in the graph container. So , I can't fix this case and need some help.

Comment: What if you move B toward bottom right or A toward upper left? Are you following a specific example or is this your own implementation? Can you share some code to better understand what's happening?

Comment: graph.insertVertex(parent, null, 'A', 400, 400, 50, 50, 'shape=lineEllipse;portConstraint=north;');
graph.insertVertex(parent,null,'B',20,20,50,50,'shape=doubleEllipse');

Comment: <div id="graphContainer"
 style="width:500px;background:url('editors/images/grid.gif');cursor:default;vertical-align: middle;height: 500px;top:200px;left: 30%;float: left;overflow: auto;">
 </div>

Comment: this has solved